# ID Workbench Generate XHTML from DITA with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, eclipse, xhtml, dita

I am trying to generate xhtml from dita using the ID Workbench (which works fine =)), but I also need to have every generated html file with a snippet of Javascript at the top of it. This javascript will be the same for every file.

Is there a way to add this in somehow? I can't seem to find any answers?

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, ID Workbench uses the open toolkit to generate output, albeit with some customization. These steps work with the open toolkit, do not require creating a customization, and should work with ID Workbench as well.

1. Create a file with the javascript that you need to add, enclosed in a  tag. For example:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript"><!--
       window.alert("Hello world!");
   --></script>
   ```

   This file must be well-formed or it will not be used.
2. Add one of the following build parameters, depending on whether you need the snippet to be included in the HTML `<head>` or `<body>`.

   - To include in `<head>`: `args.hdf="path_to_snippet"`
   - To include in `<body>`: `args.hdr="path_to_snippet"`
3. Build your XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a customization to do it the official way. I'm not familiar enough with workbench to tell you how to integrate it. Don't be afraid of creating your own post-process that adds the javascript after the html files have been created.